# mysql installation on Ubuntu 18.04, E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: 18.04, mysql

I tried to install mysql on ubuntu 18.04 using:

```
$ sudo apt install mysql-server
```

I got the message:

> dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (dependency problems)

I followed the steps at:

[dpkg: error processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43446218/dpkg-error-processing-package-mysql-server-dependency-problems)

I did:

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql*
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Now I am getting the message:

```
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.130ubuntu3.13) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-167-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Somebody please guide me.

==Updated Feb 12 2022

```
$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

```
> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
> state information... Done The following packages were automatically
> installed and are no longer required:   cuda-command-line-tools-10-1
> cuda-command-line-tools-11-2 cuda-compiler-10-1   cuda-compiler-11-2
> cuda-cudart-10-1 cuda-cudart-11-2 cuda-cudart-dev-10-1  
> cuda-cudart-dev-11-2 cuda-cufft-10-1 cuda-cufft-dev-10-1
> cuda-cuobjdump-10-1   cuda-cuobjdump-11-2 cuda-cupti-10-1
> cuda-cupti-11-2 cuda-cupti-dev-11-2   cuda-curand-10-1
> cuda-curand-dev-10-1 cuda-cusolver-10-1   cuda-cusolver-dev-10-1
> cuda-cusparse-10-1 cuda-cusparse-dev-10-1   cuda-cuxxfilt-11-2
> cuda-documentation-10-1 cuda-documentation-11-2   cuda-driver-dev-10-1
> cuda-driver-dev-11-2 cuda-drivers-460 cuda-gdb-10-1   cuda-gdb-11-2
> cuda-gpu-library-advisor-10-1 cuda-libraries-10-1  
> cuda-libraries-11-2 cuda-libraries-dev-10-1 cuda-libraries-dev-11-2  
> cuda-license-10-1 cuda-memcheck-10-1 cuda-memcheck-11-2  
> cuda-misc-headers-10-1 cuda-npp-10-1 cuda-npp-dev-10-1
> cuda-nsight-10-1   cuda-nsight-11-2 cuda-nsight-compute-10-1
> cuda-nsight-compute-11-2   cuda-nsight-systems-10-1
> cuda-nsight-systems-11-2 cuda-nvcc-10-1   cuda-nvcc-11-2
> cuda-nvdisasm-10-1 cuda-nvdisasm-11-2 cuda-nvgraph-10-1  
> cuda-nvgraph-dev-10-1 cuda-nvjpeg-10-1 cuda-nvjpeg-dev-10-1  
> cuda-nvml-dev-10-1 cuda-nvml-dev-11-2 cuda-nvprof-10-1
> cuda-nvprof-11-2   cuda-nvprune-10-1 cuda-nvprune-11-2 cuda-nvrtc-10-1
> cuda-nvrtc-11-2   cuda-nvrtc-dev-10-1 cuda-nvrtc-dev-11-2
> cuda-nvtx-10-1 cuda-nvtx-11-2   cuda-nvvp-10-1 cuda-nvvp-11-2
> cuda-samples-10-1 cuda-samples-11-2   cuda-sanitizer-11-2
> cuda-sanitizer-api-10-1 cuda-toolkit-10-1   cuda-toolkit-11-2
> cuda-tools-10-1 cuda-tools-11-2 cuda-visual-tools-10-1  
> cuda-visual-tools-11-2 freeglut3 freeglut3-dev libcublas-11-2
> libcublas-dev   libcublas-dev-11-2 libcublas10 libcufft-11-2
> libcufft-dev-11-2   libcurand-11-2 libcurand-dev-11-2 libcusolver-11-2
> libcusolver-dev-11-2   libcusparse-11-2 libcusparse-dev-11-2
> libnpp-11-2 libnpp-dev-11-2   libnvidia-cfg1-460 libnvidia-common-460
> libnvidia-compute-460   libnvidia-decode-460 libnvidia-encode-460
> libnvidia-extra-460   libnvidia-fbc1-460 libnvidia-gl-460
> libnvidia-ifr1-460 libnvjpeg-11-2   libnvjpeg-dev-11-2
> libqt5positioning5 libqt5sensors5 libqt5webchannel5   libqt5webkit5
> libxi-dev libxmu-dev libxmu-headers linux-headers-4.15.0-143  
> linux-headers-4.15.0-143-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-143-generic  
> nsight-compute-2020.3.0 nsight-compute-2020.3.1
> nsight-compute-2022.1.0   nsight-systems-2020.4.3
> nsight-systems-2021.5.2 nvidia-compute-utils-460   nvidia-dkms-460
> nvidia-kernel-common-460 nvidia-kernel-source-460   nvidia-modprobe
> nvidia-utils-460 qml-module-qtgraphicaleffects  
> qml-module-qtquick-controls qml-module-qtquick-dialogs  
> qml-module-qtquick-layouts qml-module-qtquick-privatewidgets  
> qml-module-qtquick-window2 qml-module-qtquick2 shim  
> xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-460 Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove
> them. 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. 2
> not fully installed or removed. After this operation, 0 B of
> additional disk space will be used. Setting up mysql-server-5.7
> (5.7.37-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
> /var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-5.7.postinst: line 206:
> /usr/share/mysql-common/configure-symlinks: No such file or directory
> dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure): 
> installed mysql-server-5.7 package post-installation script subprocess
> returned error exit status 127 No apport report written because the
> error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
>                           dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:  mysql-server depends on
> mysql-server-5.7; however:   Package mysql-server-5.7 is not
> configured yet.
> 
> dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):  dependency
> problems - leaving unconfigured Errors were encountered while
> processing:  mysql-server-5.7  mysql-server E: Sub-process
> /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) zulfi@lc2530hz:~$
```

==Error messages:

Hi,

I tried:

```
$ sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

I got the following message:

```
> Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.37-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
> /var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-5.7.postinst: line 206:
> /usr/share/mysql-common/configure-symlinks: No such file or directory
> dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure): 
> installed mysql-server-5.7 package post-installation script subprocess
> returned error exit status 127 dpkg: dependency problems prevent
> configuration of mysql-server:  mysql-server depends on
> mysql-server-5.7; however:   Package mysql-server-5.7 is not
> configured yet.
> 
> dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):  dependency
> problems - leaving unconfigured No apport report written because the
> error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
>                                                                                                           Errors were encountered while processing:  mysql-server-5.7 
> mysql-server E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Then I tried:

```
$ sudo apt install mysql-server-5.7
```

```
> Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.37-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
> /var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-5.7.postinst: line 206:
> /usr/share/mysql-common/configure-symlinks: No such file or directory
> dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure): 
> installed mysql-server-5.7 package post-installation script subprocess
> returned error exit status 127 dpkg: dependency problems prevent
> configuration of mysql-server:  mysql-server depends on
> mysql-server-5.7; however:   Package mysql-server-5.7 is not
> configured yet.
> 
> dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):  dependency
> problems - leaving unconfigured No apport report written because the
> error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
>                                                                                                           Errors were encountered while processing:  mysql-server-5.7 
> mysql-server E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

## Please guide me.

~$ lsb_release -d

Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS

```
$ sudo apt update
```

> [sudo] password for zulfi:  Ign:1
> http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64
> InRelease Hit:2 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic
> InRelease
> Hit:3 https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease
> Ign:4
> http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64
> InRelease
> Get:5 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian buster InRelease [54.0
> kB]
> Hit:6
> http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64
> Release
> Hit:7
> http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64
> Release
> Hit:8 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease
> Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
> [88.7 kB]
> Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
> Hit:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
> Get:13 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
> [88.7 kB]
> Hit:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ethereum/ethereum/ubuntu bionic
> InRelease
> Get:16 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
> [74.6 kB]
> Get:17 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64
> DEP-11 Metadata [55.3 kB]
> Hit:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu bionic
> InRelease                                        Get:19
> http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64
> DEP-11 Metadata [59.4 kB]
> Get:20 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64
> DEP-11 Metadata [296 kB]
> Get:21 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse
> amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,460 B]
> Hit:22
> http://ppa.launchpad.net/maarten-baert/simplescreenrecorder/ubuntu
> bionic InRelease
> Get:23 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe
> amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [301 kB]
> Get:24 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse
> amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,464 B]
> Get:25 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe
> amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [9,268 B]                  Hit:26
> http://ppa.launchpad.net/wireshark-dev/stable/ubuntu bionic InRelease
> Ign:27 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian 18.04
> InRelease Err:28 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian
> 18.04 Release   404  Not Found [IP: 173.222.52.87 80] Reading package lists... Done E: The repository
> 'http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian 18.04 Release' does
> not have a Release file. N: Updating from such a repository can't be
> done securely, and is therefore disabled by default. N: See
> apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration
> details. @lc2530hz:~$

Comment: Please [edit] to include the FULL output of `sudo apt --fix-broken install`

Comment: It looks like you're running the original release of Ubuntu 18.04. You may want to install all system updates before installing MySQL ...

Comment: @Someone, hi, I added the output of sudo apt --fix-broken install, I am getting the same E: Sub-process error message, please guide m.

Comment: @matigo, please guide me how to install all system updates.

Comment: First you ensure apt is up to date: `sudo apt update`. Then perform a distribution upgrade: `sudo apt dist-upgrade`.

Comment: @matigo, Hi my friend, I am still getting the error, I posted it on the main thread. Please guide me.

Comment: Please add the output of `lsb_release -d` and `sudo apt update`

Comment: @Someone, please guide me.

Comment: @user2994783 Try running `touch /usr/share/mysql-common/configure-symlinks` then try running `sudo apt -f install`

Comment: @Someone, getting error:  $ touch /usr/share/mysql-common/configure-symlinks
touch: cannot touch '/usr/share/mysql-common/configure-symlinks': No such file or directory@lc2530hz:~$

Comment: @Someone,:/usr/share$ ls mysql-common
=> ls: cannot access 'mysql-common': No such file or directory

Comment: @user2994783 That's weird. If I were you I'd completely purge MySQL and reinstall it. Generally, the installation script should automatically create those directories, but it hasn't... Some files and directories are missing. Did you remove the pre-installation script or any removal script??

Comment: Also, you're using a lot of 3rd party repositories... That's a common cause of these problems. You shouldn't use 3rd party repositories on an old LTS release. (*it's up to you*, but if you want to add 3rd party repositories, you should use the current stable release (impish) or at least the newest LTS release)